# MySQL to select or insert based on condition

Tags: mysql

How to do this in a single MySQL query:

```
if (select count(*)..)=10
  select a record from the same table
else
  insert a record into the same table
```

Comment: I can't see how you would in a single query either read or write, I mean how should the client read/write the data? You could write a procedure or function for that which takes all parameters for a potential insert and returns potentially the read data.

Comment: I'll fetch the result in PHP and then proceed according to the data returned. I'm logging IP addresses to protect from brute force attacks; number 10 is actually less. Selection is how many minutes the client should wait. Insertion is logging his IP with time.

Comment: What you want is a stored procedure.  Take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751881/mysql-stored-procedure-with-if-then-else and then read up on MySQL stored procs.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Then make the decision in PHP, I would suggest. Count the values, reject if more than 9, insert otherwise. You could even avoid mysql for that if the site has high traffic with using redis or memcache.

Comment: @EdManet I don't know what are MySQL procedures or stored procedures, I'm trying to understand from the link. Can I use them through PHP? Please give little more guidance through an answer.

Comment: @flaschenpost I've never used caching, know only the basics. The idea is very nice. It'll be faster than MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use one single SQL command (but I don't know why) you can use a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `select_or_insert`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    COMMENT 'blah blah'
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `your_table`) = 10) THEN
        SELECT ... FROM ... ;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO ... ;
    END IF;
END;
```

To invoke the Procedure you will issue the following command:

```
CALL `select_or_insert`();
```

If the `SELECT` is executed, the statement will return a resultset.

Answer (score 1):

As long as only one webserver is involved, I would try APC http://php.net/manual/de/book.apc.php with some nice system of timeout.

Say for example: if an IP has already sent a request in the last 2 seconds, it's current request should be refused and the timeout changes to 4 seconds, after that 10 seconds etc.

```
if ($timeoutLevel = apc_fetch("locked_" . $ip)){
    $timeoutLevel++;
    $timeout = getNextTimeout($timeoutLevel);
    apc_store("locked_".$ip, $timeoutLevel, $timeout);
    show_my_error_page(get_friendly_text("please do not try again for $timeout seconds! You are Blocked!"));
    exit();
}
else{
    $timeoutLevel = 1;
    $timeout = INITIAL_PAGE_TIMEOUT;
    apc_store("locked_".$ip, $timeoutLevel, $timeout);
}
```

That should cost at max around 50 Byte per ip of the last x seconds, so if it is not a DDOS then the webserver should have that RAM.

But be careful: some html-pages contain references to css, javascript, images, sounds, ajax-calls might come later, json-requests etc. pp.

After $timeout seconds APC automatically drops that value, so no need to hire a cleaning women.